# running python script over sysmd unit: time.sleep of more than 60 seconds does not work

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi, mqtt, systemd

I am running a systemd unit python script at my RaspberryPi to send temperature data automatically when the Pi has power. When time.sleep is at 60 seconds everything works fine. But when time.sleep is longer (120 seconds or more), it only sends one value when the script starts and afterwards I do not get any more values. Can someone help?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import ssl

# Set up DHT22 sensor
dht_sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
dht_pin = 4  # GPIO pin number the sensor is connected to

username = 'master:mqttuser'
secret = 'ifYrtDSc'
host = '192.168.0.65'
port = 8883
clientID = 'raspi_ka'
assetID = '3nRdfjgE0Ga'


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    mqtt_client.subscribe("$SYS/#")


def on_publish(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(clientID)
mqtt_client.username_pw_set(username, password=secret)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
mqtt_client.tls_set_context(context)
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
mqtt_client.on_publish = on_publish
mqtt_client.connect(host, port=port)

# Continuously read and send temperature values
while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(dht_sensor, dht_pin)
    if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
        mqtt_client.publish(f"master/{clientID}/writeattributevalue/temperature/{assetID}", temperature)
        mqtt_client.publish(f"master/{clientID}/writeattributevalue/humidity/{assetID}", humidity)
    else:
        print("Failed to read temperature sensor data")
    time.sleep(120)

# Disconnect MQTT client
mqtt_client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are disconnected due to a timeout. You have to set the `keepalive` argument to connect.

```
mqtt_client.connect(host, port=port, keepalive=120)
```

Note that `time.sleep()` is not accurate. It might be prolonged by an arbitrary amount. You probably want to use the `loop` function of the MQTT client instead.

```
while True:
    ...
    mqtt_client.loop(timeout=120)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I use ```mqtt_client.loop(timeout=120)``` instead of time.sleep(120) it publishes way more often then every two minutes, nearly every second. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. `loop` will return as soon as data is available, or the timeout expires.

Comment: You could check the time passed, or maybe just giving a little room for error between the `keepalive` duration and `sleep` will work as well; keepalive for 150 seconds and sleep for 120 will almost certainly not fail.

Comment: The values are now published as they should, thanks for that! But two things are still not as expected: First I get no printed line when publishing and second the connection gets still disconnected every 90 seconds, but immediately afterwards it is connected again. Do you have an idea here as well? Cheers

Comment: my logfile tells me: INFO:root:Unexpected disconnection. Reason: Connection Refused: unacceptable protocol version.

Comment: No, sorry. I have no idea.